# Xamarin Android DateTime behaves differently in the Emulator and Actual Phone

Tags: android, datetime, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

Using several Android Emulators at Release configuation, the DateTime class behaves OK.
But when I install it on an android phone, it behaves differently.

Example:

1. The format of the DateTime in the Emulator is 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt' but when installed in actual phone the format changes to 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
2. When using the DateTime.Now, the Emulator return the current date and time of phone but the installed app in the actual phone returns 1/1/0001.
3. Also the DateTime.TryParse works in the Emulator but fails in the installed app.

Here is my Proguard.cfg settings

```
 -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

 -keep class com.google.firebase.provider.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.firebase.provider.**

 -keep class com.google.firebase.iid.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.firebase.iid.**

 -keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
 -dontwarn android.support.v7.widget.**

 -keep class android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout { *; }
 -dontwarn android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout
```

Here is a part of my code:

```
 DateTime newDateValue = DateTime.Now;

 string forParsing = "10/23/2020 4:40:59 AM";                       
 bool response = DateTime.TryParse(forParsing, out newDateValue);
```

Here is my Android Option Settings:
[image: Android Options:]

Comment: you need to be sure the locale settings on your phone and emulator are the same.  DateTime default output format and parsing defaults will vary depending on locale.

Comment: @Jason, wow thanks! it worked. Problem solved!